# C# AppDomains and Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, marshalling, appdomain

I've come with a little question that keeps me awake all night. Maybe it's easy to understand, but I can't, yet.

Which is better? An AppDomain inside a Thread, or a Thread inside a new AppDomain?

So wich is the diference between:

```
static void Main() {
    AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain ("NewDomain");
    Thread t = new Thread (delegate() { ad.DoCallBack (SomeMethod); });
    t.Start();
}

static void SomeMethod() { }
```

And:

```
public void Start() {
    myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllFileName);
    Type myType = AssEnsamblado.GetType(myAseembly.Type);
    MethodInfo myMethod = tipo.GetMethod(@"StartDLL");
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    Thread thrBase = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate() { myMethod.Invoke(obj, null); }));
    thrBase.Start();
}
```

The snippet above is being executed in a class witch inherits from MBRO, to create a remote instance and call the method that contains that code.

Comment: what's the motivation? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi! The main goal is communicacion between two app domains through WCF interprocess. That is already done, but I haven't found a nice way to shut down the client, instead of aborting the thread. So I keep researching, maybe if is better to have a remoting class to control and execute methods, or control the thread that holds the new appdomain. Maybe this approach is wrong. So, I keep researching. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a risk and say that once your code is executing in a new Application Domain, it makes little or no difference at all either way.

The issue is the crossing to the other application domain, which *may* require serialization/marshalling of objects (if it supports it) that are passed/returned to the new application domain.

Comment: Hi! I'm already marshaling objects, I need it to call the methos that initialize the client. However I'm still wondering wich could be the best way, in order to shut down the client. Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

Steer away from such code (either of the samples). It will make your life hell, unless you enjoy spending weeks in debugging weird exceptions here and there.

Face the *root* problem - shut down the remote job gracefully. There are usually many ways to do that, including different ways to cancel or terminate it, but calling a dirty hack `Thread.Abort()` is just evil.

Comment: Hi! I agree, aborting is not the best way, software and humans. I already though to shut down the client with an event to the class where the channel is being created and opened. Let's see if this works. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @BlackCath perhaps check the `Task` class, it supports cancellation or maybe post your client-server code in another question and see what people think is the best way to do that.